# how to swap sections with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner with HTML5 and Javascript and I'd like to create a basic function that swap the section's positions with a event.

The function 1 is working, swapping the section "con" to top, but the function 2 doesn't work.

Please, someone can help me?

```
function swap1() 
{
document.getElementById("top").style.position = "absolute";  
document.getElementById("con").style.top = "50px";
}

function swap2() 
{
document.getElementById("con").style.position = "fixed"; 
document.getElementById("top").style.bottom = "300px";
}
```

---

```
<section id="top" onmousedown="swap1()">

<video width="500" height="500" controls>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>
</video>

</section>



<section id="con" onmouseover="swap2()">

<hr>

<p>Text.</p>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because after running ur first function, Section CON goes behind the TOP section thats why can see it but u cant fire mouseover function on that [con] section..

u have set z-index to achieve that.

[check this out](http://jsbin.com/izusar/1/) http://jsbin.com/izusar/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/vQcrh/

```
function swap1() 
{
    var top=document.getElementById("top");
    var con=document.getElementById("con");

    con.style.bottom=top.style.top="auto";
    con.style.top=top.style.bottom="0";
}

function swap2() 
{
    var top=document.getElementById("top");
    var con=document.getElementById("con");

    con.style.top=top.style.bottom="auto";
    con.style.bottom=top.style.top="0";
}
```

Notice how I preset the styles so I could swap them:

```
#top
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#con
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just swap the section elements then this may helpfull.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function swap(obj) {
                //var firstChildID = jQuery('#container section:first-child').attr('id');
                jQuery(obj).prependTo('#container');
                //if (firstChildID == jQuery(obj).attr('id')) 
                //    jQuery(obj).appendTo('#container');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <section id="top" onclick="javascript:swap(this);">
                <video width="500" height="500" controls>
                    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
            </section>
            <section id="con" onclick="javascript:swap(this);">
                <hr/>
                <p>Text.</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```